# How can I make my application check if Adobe flash player is installed on a PC?

Tags: c#, winforms, activex

My application needs Adobe Flash Player to function properly and I need it to check whether it's installed or not.

So how can I make my application check if Adobe flash player is installed on a PC?

My program is written in C#

Comment: I don't get the question. What do you want to do, in which situation?

Comment: What does C# have to do with Flash Player?

Comment: I guess the user wants to scan the system for installation of flash player , and wants to do it using C# , this question needs to be modified and migrated back to stackoverflow

Answer (score 7):

Check if this registry key exists:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer
```

Then, you can check the installed version (if installed) from here:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer\CurrentVersion
```

[Here](http://www.geekpedia.com/KB60_How-to-check-if-a-registry-key-or-subkey-already-exists.html) you can find code on how to check existence of registry key.

Answer (score 4):

Following code return current version string of flash.

```
private string GetFlashPlayerVersionString()
{
    RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer");
    if (regKey != null)
    {
        string flashVersion = Convert.ToString(regKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion"));
        return flashVersion;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Open the Flash folder (C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash) and whatever is listed there would be your Flash Player files.

Comment: You can't be sure that the Flash player _always_ installs here - use Sarwar's answer.